How to know if this is a bandpass or stopband filter?
I have this filter specifications (frequencies in Hz):
fp1 = 500; % Passband (start)
fp2 = 20e6; % Passband (end)
fs1 = 35e3; % Stopband (start)
fs2 = 80e3; % Stopband (end)
Amax = 0.2; % Maximum attenuation in the passband (dB)
Amin = 40; % Minimum attenuation in the stopband (dB)

Is this a bandpass or stopband filter?

Hi! Welcome here! You have probably the definition of "bandpass" and "band-stop filter" at hand. Can you explain which problems you have applying it these two definitions to this filter specification? Then we might be able to actually help you understand what you need to understand to answer this kind of question yourself.

Hi! Thank you! I am trying to simulate the graph of this filter on matlab. But I don't know if this is a bandpass or stopband filter, and I need this to use the appropriate function.
The passband is 500 Hz to 20MHz
The stopband is 35kHZ to 80kHz.
I'm confused whether this is a bandpass or stopband filter.

you mean "band-stop filter", not "stopband filter". "Stop-band" is property of many filter types.

so, is there any reason why you think this needs to be either of these two types?

Yeah, I mean band-stop filter, sorry. No, there is no reason why I am thinking this needs to be either of these two types. I really want to know which type is.

OK, but if you don't think it's either of these types (and it really is neither of these types), why are you asking about these specific types of filters only?

Because I have a college project with these specifications, and I'm confused about identifying what type of filter it is.

it's neither of these types. This filter has no special name: but you seem to have specified it well enough.

What is the type?

There is no name for this type of filter.

So, to use the matlab function "butter", how can I specify the filter type?

do you read what I write? This is neither a band-stop nor a band-pass filter.

and why would you design this as a Butterworth filter? That seems to be the completely wrong approach with a filter specification like this.

Yes, I wrote, thanks for the answer. My college project is to design on matlab a Butteroworth, Chebyshev and Cauer filter with this specifications.

Is the intent to chain calls to both the MATLAB functions bandpass and bandstop to implement a cascaded filter?

I need to introduce the Butteworth, Chebyshev and Cauer approximation functions for the specifications I mentioned in matlab.

That would be an explanation, though I wonder what sense that would make with a Butterworth implementation of both the bandpass and -stop filters: you'd need a buffer in between both stages (or need to go for rather extreme values) in a passive element implementation, and at that point, you'd rather design an active (bi-elliptic?) filter.

@RonildoAndrade The Butterworth filter design method doesn't allow you to specify these many parameters of your frequency response. As Chester Gillon says, you might concatenate a bandpass and a bandstop Butterworth filter to achieve this response, but it's then a joint optimization design problem, and that's rather hard!

That's because the band-pass filter will already have some attenuation where you want to put your stopband, but the band-stop filter will also have some ripple in where you want to put your passband. So, to achieve what you need, you will need to make at least one of your two filters that you need to combine rather high-order, and at that point the question is why you're not directly using a different design method.

Unfortunately I need to use this approximation function with the specifications as well. How can you identify that this is not a bandpass or band reject filter?
Can you detail which specifications do not allow me to do the butterworth approximation? Is it because the bandwidth is too large?

@RonildoAndrade did you draw your filter specification on paper, with a pencil? If not, do so, now. Vertical axis: attenuation, from 0 dB to -40. Horizontal Axis: frequency, from 0 Hz to 25 MHz. First, draw the specification of the pass-band: a line from 500 Hz to 20 MHz, at height -0.2 dB. You color the "upper" side of that line green, because that's what is OK for the filter to be. Then you do the same with the stopband, from 35 kHz to 80 kHz, at height -40 dB. and you color the area above that line red, because that's what your filter needs to not allow through. Now compare that

to the wikipedia drawings of "band-pass filter" and "band-stop filter". And explain to me how any of this goes together!

Ok, it's not really a band-pass filter. However, I don't understand why it can't be a band-stop filter. The passband is 500 to 20MHz, and there is a cutoff frequency from 35kHz to 80kHz.

the thing is: when you say you have a passband, like your filter specification does, then that means "no cutouts". The spec says "nowhere between 500 Hz and 20 MHz may attenuation be higher than 0.2 dB". That is not negotiable. The spec also says "nowhere between 35 and 80 kHz might the attenuation be less than 40 dB". That means these two aspects of your specification contradict. It is logically impossible to build a single filter that fulfils this! So, when I look at that I come to the conclusion that you were probably not asked to build something impossible.

so you were probably asked to build two filters, one band-pass and one band-stop filer.

Ok. If my specifications change to:
Bandpass: 400 Hz to 500 Hz.
Stopband: 80 Hz to 50kHz.
Amax (dB) = 0.8
Amin (dB) = 45
Is that possible?

it looks like an impossible filter.  the two bands overlap  attenuation at 500Hz can't be both less than or equal 0.8dB and more than or equal 45dB

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
